# user mode driver (umdf) c++ http request

Tags: c++, kmdf, wdm, umdf

I have developed a umdf2 driver and in some point it needs to communicate to a remote server to fetch some data. I am wondering is there any easy way (e.g. library) to do the http requests (GET, POST) in Windows user mode? I have never used winsock2 and I am not sure how easy/possible it's to use it?

Currently, I am using a kind of Pipe to hand this job to another app that resides upper level and uses Windows SDK to do this smoothly.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WinHTTP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-start-page

filler filler filler

Comment: Captured from the link you shared it says "WinHTTP supports desktop client applications, Windows services, and Windows server-based applications." Nothing is mentioned about user mode drivers.

Comment: A UMDF driver is just a DLL loaded into a regular user-mode process.